# Is there a way to create a histogram in R using ggplot so that only the vertical lines of the bins that are protruding show?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am currently creating some histograms in R using ggplot that have many bins and a large data set (850 000 elements).

As a result the vertical lines of each bin are filling in the area under the histogram with the line colour due to there close proximity. I would ideally like this to be clear so I can plot another histogram on the same plot.

Ideally, I would like a histogram with the bin lines hidden where they overlap with another bin so It looks similar to a line plot.

Below is the ggplot code I'm using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=eev)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 18,color="black") +
  xlim(0,10000) +
  scale_y_log10(name="Log of Counts", labels = scales::comma) +
  xlab("Incident Energy in eV")
```

I can't really fiddle around with the bin size too much because I need the definition from the naarrow bins.

I've had a look through the ggplot documentation but can't find what I'm after.

Cheers

Edit:
Following MrFlicks advice I've made some reproducible code

```
a<-runif(10000, 0, 10)
b<-seq(0,9.999, by = 1/1000)
var<-data.frame(a,b)

ggplot(var, aes(x=a)) +
         geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.3, col = "black", fill = "#ffffff00")
```

This gives the following output
[Histogram with bin lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CTcH.png)

However I need the final histogram to look like this

[Histogram without overlapping bin lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNlNB.png)

I can't use `geom_freqpoly` as the data needs to be presented as a histogram.

[Here is the current histogram for some of the real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW2wo.png)

Cheers again.

Also, apologies this is the first time posting on stack overflow if my post layout is off etc.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do you want `geom_freqpoly` rather than `geom_histogram`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using `hist` to generate the values then plotting in ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
x = hist(rchisq(1000, df = 4), 100)
df = data.frame(
  x = rep(x$breaks, each=2), 
  y = c(0, rep(x$counts, each = 2), 0))
  
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill='grey80') +
  geom_line(col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked and is exactly what I am after

Comment: glad it helped.  I simplified it slightly using geom_polygon.  Also switched it to plot the area before the line, which gives sharper image (avoids area overplotting the line slightly).

Answer (score 0):

Setting a transparent `color` like #ffffff00 (the last two digits setting opacity to zero) should do the trick. Control the *fill* colour (the inner of the histogram columns) with, well: `fill`.

Example:

```
data.frame(x = rnorm(10000)) %>%
    ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(aes(x), 
                   fill = 'blue', 
                   binwidth = .025,
                   col='#ffffff00'
                   )
```

Note that while you can increase the border thickness of the columns with the `size` argument, setting size = 0 does not fully remove the border.